# Find third largest quote ever created for each of the accounts in the EC1 area

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Can anyone help I'm new to SQL and trying to figure out the below question see image for the table structure;

[image]

Question = Select account name, contact last name, case number, quote number, quote date and quote value for the  f third-largest quote ever created for each of the accounts in the EC1 area

So far I got;

```
Select 
    a.accountname, cc.lastname, c.casenumber, 
    q.quotenumber, q.quotedate, q.quotevalue 
from 
    TBL_Quote q 
Left join 
    TBL_case c On q.caseid = c.caseid 
Left join 
    tbl_contact cc On c.contactID = cc. contactID 
Left join    
    tbl_account a On a.accountid = cc.accountid 
Where 
    left(a.postcode, 3) like 'EC1'
```

and for the third:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 value 
     FROM tbl_quote 
     ORDER BY value DESC) a 
ORDER BY value
```

I can't seem to combine the top 3 and the query is it best to overpartion by ?

Comment: This reads like a homework question. What have you tried, why didn't it work? Or what research have you done, and what about it didn't you understand>?

Comment: Hi Larnu,  that's right it's a question from an online question I found I'm trying to practice as much as can.

Comment: Select a.accountname, cc.lastname, c.casenumber, q.quotenumber, q.quotedate ,q.quotevalue
from TBL_Quote q
Left join TBL_case c
On q.caseid = c.caseid
Left join tbl_contact cc
On c.contactID = cc. contactID
Left join tbl_account a 
On a.accountid = cc.accountid
Where left(a.postcode,3) like 'EC1'






SELECT TOP 1 value
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 value
      FROM tbl_quote
      ORDER BY value DESC
      ) a
ORDER BY value     i have got to the above and can't seem to marry the top 3 and the query

Comment: @Huss1: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62177337/edit) to add the query directly in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest joins and a row-limiting clause:

```
select ac.accountName, co.lastName, ca.caseNumber, qu.quoteNumber
from tbl_account       ac
inner join tbl_contact co on co.accountId = ac.accountId
inner join tbl_case    ca on ca.contactId = co.contactId
inner join tbl_quote   qu on qu.caseId    = ca.quoteId
where ac.postcode like 'EC1%'
order by len(qu.value) desc
offset 2 rows fetch next 1 row only
```